# Angular cdkOverlay disable close

Tags: angular, angular-material, overlay

I implemented Angular Material cdkOverlay based on the way described here:

https://github.com/mainawycliffe/ng-cdk-overlay-demo/tree/master/src/app

I would like to disable close. In the API (https://beta-angular-material-io.firebaseapp.com/cdk/overlay/api) there is the input:

@Input('cdkConnectedOverlayDisableClose')
disableClose: boolean

But I do't know how to use. In the overlay config there is no such field: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/cdk/overlay/overlay-config.ts

How could I switch the default value from false to true?

Help is really appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Update:

as mentioned in the comment, I tried to add the input field cdkConnectedOverlayDisableClose to the template. But unfortunately it doesn't work.

See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/overlay-demo-zodwyq?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

What do I miss?

Comment: submit the code piece where you added the overlay

Comment: but from the documentation you can see it has an input that is called cdkConnectedOverlayDisableClose, yo use it `[cdkConnectedOverlayDisableClose]="true"` i would but in the template where its connected

Comment: I tried similar to this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/overlay-demo-zodwyq?file=app%2Fapp.component.html but it's not working.